# How to remove "Add New" button from Asset Publisher for Power User?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need to remove "Add New" button from Asset Publisher portlet for the role "Power User" in Liferay 6.1.
How can I do it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Add New" Button only appears when a user has permissions to create one of the assets displayed in AssetPublisher. It seems that your users/power users have permission to create content - this can be WebContent, Blogs or others. For example this typically happens in their own personal site where they have write permissions by default.

You can either remove that permission from the Power User, use standard users (there has been a [recent blogpost](https://www.liferay.com/web/milen.dyankov/blog/-/blogs/the-power-user-is-back) about the difference between the two) or, if the permission is ok, just the UI should disappear either override the AssetPublisher UI with a hook (remove the button there) or use the simple CSS-trick ("display:none") in the portlet's "Look&Feel/Advanced Styling" section

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I could do it by creating Hook. 
How to give "Add New" permission for Asset Publisher for a custom role? I just created one custom regular role and gave some permissions... Now "Add New" button is visible in Asset Publisher portlet, but the user belongs to that custom role is not able to add any assets...the window is not opening properly. How can I give "Add" permission for Asset Publisher portlet for my custom role?

Comment: You don't give "Add" Permissions for "generic" Assets, but to specific ones, like "Web Content" or "Blog" - this should help, or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. The "Add New" button is visible in "Asset Publisher" portlet. But the user is not able to add any assets. When user clicks on "Add New" button a small BLANK window is opening. Why window is not opening properly?
 The user is belongs to my custom role. What permission should I give to allow him to add assets?